# Parsing string "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw" to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to parse the string

> Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw

to `DateTime`

I've tried:

```
var datestring = "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw";
DateTime.TryParse(datestring, out expDt);
```

but it's not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look into [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is the Date always in this formt or do is this just an example for one possibilty?

Comment: As the other comment indicates, you have to first make sure what format is used to generate the string. It is not in any easy-to-use standard format, and it would be better if the generating side can generate other formats instead.

Comment: Have a look at http://nodatime.org/ for a library that can also deal with the timezone name as given.

Comment: I don't think that `Europe/Warsaw` is any standard - it is free text description of time zone.

Comment: It is an official timezone name in the IANA timezone database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
string datestring = "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw";
// remove "Europe/Warsaw" because it wont be used.
datestring = datestring.Substring(0, datestring.LastIndexOf(' '));
// now datestring looks like "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12"
// so you should adapt the format:
string dateFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
// now you can use DateTime.ParseExact to retrieve DateTime object
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, dateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This should parse to correct `DateTime` object.

Calling `dt.ToString()` should return something like **14.01.2017 12:12:12**

**EDIT:**

For everyone else that assumes that `DateTime` object is somewhat aware of *TimeZone* or is it dependant on it. Please read this answer [Get timezone from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576740/get-timezone-from-datetime)

That's why for me it was useless to extract *TimeZone* from the string. Because it would have no impact on `DateTime` object itself. If ( but I doubt that ) someone has the same issue and need this informations then here's the example :

```
string datestring = "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw";
// remove "Europe/Warsaw" because it wont be used.
string datestr = new string(datestring.Take(datestring.LastIndexOf(' ')));
// now datestring looks like "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12"
// so you should adapt the format:
string dateFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
// now you can use DateTime.ParseExact to retrieve DateTime object
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, dateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string timezonestr = new string(datestring.Skip(datestring.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));

try {
    TimeZoneInfo timzeone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezonestr);
} catch { /* probably an error because there's no timezone called Europe/Warsaw */ }
```

Comment: Note that the timezone information "Europe/Warsaw" is lost here.

Comment: @NineBerry Yes but it's not relevant in `DateTime`  object itself. And it's fairly easy to preserve both informations : `string timezone = new string(datestring.Skip(datestring.LastIndexOf(' ')));`

Comment: @m.rogalski how can a time zone information irrelevant in `DateTime` object? A date and time without time zone is useless in many cases (though sometimes of course you can assume local time zone or UTC).