# date in string format "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:00 PST" in c#.net to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i have a date in string format "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:00 PST" in c#.net console app.I want to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy format.Can anyone show me the code to do this?

Comment: These would help you to do it, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string "Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:12:12 Europe/Warsaw" to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633727/parsing-string-sat-14-jan-2017-121212-europe-warsaw-to-datetime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811442/converting-datetime-string-in-ddd-mmm-dd-hhmmss-est-yyyy-format/42812411#42812411 Note that there is no "correct" parsing in .NET of timezone abbreviations (PST)

Comment: And of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc

Comment: You have to remove the `PST`part,and then it's easy to parse the string with `ParseExact` and `"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"`

Comment: i have the string like this: String dateStr = "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:00 PST" ;I want a date time in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @VishnuMohan that's completly different from the date string in your question. Make yourself clear

Comment: it's by mistake..i have editted my previous comment

Answer (score -1):

How about converting it into a char array and then using that to reconstruct your string. for example:

```
  string str = "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:00 PST"
  var Chrarry = str.ToCharArray();
  //use a switch statament to find out that numerical value your month has for example jan = 01
  string newstr = chrarray[5] + chrarray[6] + "/"....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the format of DateTime.
Try `(dd/MM/yyyy)`

Sample code:

`DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now();
var now = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think this does not help OP. The problem is parsing  the string to a DateTime, not formatting a DateTime to string

Comment: Question was about `“Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:00 PST”` and not `"07/01/2017"`.