# CosmosDB converting DateTime properties to different timezone

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have already calculated UTC (the datetime is set to be equal to the current UTC time) for a datetime property on my entity.  I write it to CosmosDB, and I see in the DataExplorer that Microsoft has changed the datetime, doing a time conversion that puts it into the ALMT (Almaty, Kazakhstan) timezone.  Why?

Does anyone know of any settings that can be turned off to prevent this from happening?

As far as the TableEntity TimeStamp property, it is set to be +00:00, using my datetime property.

Once it has been written to CosmosDB, it's been changed all the way from 09:43 PM July 10th to 03:43 AM July 11th, or ALMT timezone.

Comment: Please define "royally jacked with." Rather, please remove such expressions and be more precise. I really don't understand your concern. Are you writing in UTC (which is advised, regardless of database)? Are you writing in local time zone? Please edit to be clearer, including relevant code, results in Cosmos DB, and expected results. Note: It doesn't help when trying to express frustration instead of defining your issue exactly.

Comment: I guess I'll have to basically encrypt my dates so Microsoft doesn't touch them since it won't know how.

Comment: Essentially, Microsoft shouldn't touch datetimes coming in to CosmosDB, since DateTime has no timezone information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576740/get-timezone-from-datetime

Since the Timestamp has a 0 offset, that's even more of a reason for Microsoft to leave it alone.

Comment: Ah, DateTime.Kind has some info in it.  I'll try changing that.

Answer (score 1):

Do this to your DateTime properties before writing them to CosmosDB, or it will convert them from whatever your local timezone (still not sure how exactly / based on what it infers that) to Utc (and if you've created the DateTime with DateTime.UtcNow, then the resulting datetime after CosmosDB converts it will be wrong):

DateTime UTCDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);

After you set up your date time properties in your entity as such, no further date conversions will occur.

Comment: If you simply create a new datetime, I believe the DateTimeKind in your date time's .Kind property is set by default to local (DateTimeKind.Local).  CosmosDB sees that and automatically converts it from your local to UTC by adding the appropriate offset.

Comment: This little trick seems to have made a difference for me when saving DateTime values in Azure's CosmosDB.  I was having a strange issue where an Azure hosted web API project would save a DateTime property in Cosmos as local time and then an Azure function that used the same data access code was writing the same DateTime to Cosmos as UTC.  When I changed my code to use DateTime.SpecifyKind(), I started to consistently see UTC formats.