# Timestamp format with Timezone C#

Tags: c#, .net

For the following code this will be the output (2020-06-05T23:02:24.554+05:30). I want the timezone without ":" in (+05:30) and expecting like (+0530). How to achieve this with datetime formatting? I can remove the colon with string operation but there should be some option in datetime format itself, Would be really good if someone suggest.

```
string date = String.Format("{0:s}.{0:fff}{0:zzz}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: What does this "requirement" of not using string functions is supposed to solve? If this is to avoid code clutter, you could simply rather create an extension method on DateTime type, so you could do `DateTime.Now.MyFormatLogic();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing such, but you can write a customized method like with out testing that takes time and return utc as you asked for:

```
public static string GetUtc(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return $"{dateTime:zzz}".Replace(":", "");
}
```

And call it

```
GetUtc(DateTime.Now);
```

This will return you +0530.

Btw I refer also to [Get timezone from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576740/get-timezone-from-datetime) for reading as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime to get what you're after.

```
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        string date = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", now.ToString("s.fff"), now.Offset.Ticks < 0 ? "-" : "+", now.Offset.ToString("hhmm"));
```

Comment: @OptionalOption yeah, good point.  I edited to take that into account.